# Skip the first line import-csv in Powershell

Tags: powershell, automation

Is it possible to skip the first line on a csv file when i do import-csv? Like in this photo. My logical header are the 'nom du client, client ipv4,etc.... But the header that powershell show me is the QM4338...
[image]

How is it possible to take the second line for my true header ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the file contents from disk with `Get-Content`, then discard the first line and pipe the remaining lines to `ConvertFrom-Csv`:

```
$csv = Get-Content $path |Select-Object -Skip 1 |ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ';'
```